# Keep selected dates after submit jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using jQuery datepicker on a **from** and **to** field for a search form. I've got the code up and running and working nicely in the search, the only thing I'm struggling with is how to keep the selected dates in the input fields *after* the form is submitted. Currently the hidden fields empty out after the search has been submitted...

```
$(function () {

    $("#from").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        firstDay: 1,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        },
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            var pieces = dateText.split('/');
            $('#queries_start_date_query_fromvalue_d').val(pieces[0]);
            $('#queries_start_date_query_fromvalue_m').val(pieces[1]);
            $('#queries_start_date_query_fromvalue_y').val(pieces[2]);
        }
    });


    $("#to").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        firstDay: 1,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        },
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            var pieces = dateText.split('/');
            $('#queries_start_date_query_tovalue_d').val(pieces[0]);
            $('#queries_start_date_query_tovalue_m').val(pieces[1]);
            $('#queries_start_date_query_tovalue_y').val(pieces[2]);
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: are you doing a postback on submit? if yes then you have to save the dates at server side. If not, then you can put it in localstorage or sessionstorage.

Comment: After the search is submitted the page refreshes and pulls through assets that match the criteria. It's on the same url but has the search string at the end. I'm not sure if this counts as a postback or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a post back. You must save the data in localStorage or sessionStorage (this is the feature of HTML5). Follow below link to implement it [Click Here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/10/local-storage-and-how-to-use-it/)

For setting the local storage, you can do it like

```
localStorage.setItem('XYZ','DropdownValue');
```

For getting the local storage, you can do it like

```
var dropdownValue= localStorage.getItem('XYZ');
```

Here, XYZ is any name you want to give to your local storage.

Comment: So could this be worked into the onselect event somehow? Sorry I'm really new to jQuery and don't yet fully understand the concepts...

Comment: Yes you can set localstorage in any event in jquery method.